# Problems with bodyline auto sizing

Tags: height, css

I want to make my bodyline which is basically my container, be at a height of:

```css
bodyline{
    height:500px;
    min-height:500px;
    height:auto !important;
}
```

but when I set it to this, it does not actually work. my footer is placed in the middle and it messes up the footer divs that are inside that. Does anyone have any suggestions. maybe I made the code wrong or something im not sure really.

example

http://jsfiddle.net/zrUSr/

please help someone.

Comment: `#footerMid ul.right`, `#footerMid ul.left`, and `#footerRight` are set at too large a height; change them all to `height:120px;` or something instead of `height:300px;`. This should fix the floating footer... Also, give `#footer` `margin:0;` to bring it further down. See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zrUSr/3/

Comment: ok but if i want to make it so that there is a min-height of 500px, in case theres not much content on that page it stays at 500px, and if more it will grow?

Comment: this is an example website for my web design class. haha. just incase you all are like, this kids making a web design site and cant make a height auto work. lol. I can get it to work on every other code i do, but this one no i cant. maybe i'm closing a div to early?

Answer (score 0):

***[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zrUSr/5/embedded/result/)***

Hey now define your div id `overflow hidden` in your css as like this

```
#bodyline {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden; // add this line 
   padding-top: 320px; //add this line
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
} 




#midSection {
    color: #000000;
    float: left;
    height: auto !important;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
    top: 320px; // remove this line
    width: 600px;
}
```

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zrUSr/5/)**

Comment: Thanks guys. I got this figured out, after fixing my errors. I then realized in the bodyline that i did not place another height:auto !important; thats my bad though over looking code sometimes. can you explain what i did wrong?

Comment: @nextlevelgamingCO can you post a jsfiddle of your solution? By the way, you're allowed to answer your own question. http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: @nextlevelgamingCO your parent div bodyline define min-height but not equal height because your used to absolute div inner bodyline if your absolute div height 300px; than give to your parent div bodyline padding-top 300px;

Comment: Sorry Rohit Azad im having a hard time understanding you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I did what some of the people told me what to do above. then found that the

```
bodyline{
 min-height:500px;
 height:500px;
height:auto !important;
}
```

height:auto was not added, so I added it so check out the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jAXp2/

and find this code

```
 /*Add this as many times as you want to*/
 <div id="midSection">
<h2>Updates</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse ultricies condimentum velit vel scelerisque. Nam id libero sit amet libero ultrices interdum dignissim nec lorem. Maecenas placerat massa sit amet augue interdum rutrum. Fusce vel lectus arcu. Quisque quis elit et lorem suscipit faucibus a ut odio. Proin ut ante consectetur dui mattis pulvinar non quis neque. Proin ultrices lectus vel orci lacinia a iaculis nibh hendrerit. Mauris sagittis aliquam odio vitae pulvinar. Suspendisse id dolor nibh, sed consectetur sem. Phasellus lacinia laoreet sem, ac ultrices libero lobortis quis. Morbi accumsan tempus neque, sed varius lectus molestie imperdiet. Vivamus porttitor facilisis nunc, sed feugiat quam adipiscing ac. Quisque dolor tellus, porta in ultrices sit amet, luctus sed nunc. Quisque sodales scelerisque orci sed ullamcorper. Nunc nisl arcu, dignissim sed tempor eget, blandit a massa. Praesent ut metus enim, in dictum felis. Integer sagittis ipsum eu mauris lacinia rhoncus. Mauris turpis ligula, dapibus nec rhoncus bibendum, tristique eu nunc. Duis dapibus blandit justo et auctor. Nunc non elit vel diam luctus ullamcorper.

Nulla elementum tristique ultricies. Etiam sit amet felis leo, non imperdiet sapien. Suspendisse venenatis, erat ac mollis sagittis, nulla arcu semper felis, a tempus dolor nibh in est. Nullam. </p>
  </div>
/*Add this as many times as you want to*/
```

add it as many times after it to see it in action.

you will see that it expands the bodyline as long as it needs to be.